# Como calcular expressões matemáticas numa string?

Tags: java

Estou fazendo uma aplicação pega uma expressão. Como fazer para calcular o resultado de uma expressão? Por exemplo: `3(-9)+50/2`. Essa expressão é digitada no `TextView`.

Comment: Essa é uma resposta mais voltada para a conversão e manipulação de uma determinada variável, não é algo exclusivo do Android. O que esse `TextView` retorna? Uma `String`? Pode-se tornar a pergunta menos independente de plataformas e útil pra você: "Como calcular expressões matemáticas em uma String?". **ps:** *just opinion*.

Comment: Também concordo @renan, acho que a única limitação seria a linguagem Java, qualquer resposta que resolva o problema é valida. Podem até surgir boas respostas.

Comment: @renan Sim concordo com tudo, mas o que aparenta é que ele não tem conhecimento de Java e que talvez para ele Java seja parte do Android, então não é nem por mal, mas sim por falta de conhecimento apenas.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Para capturar o valor do `TextView` você deverá usar o método `getText()` e converter para `string` usando `toString()`

```
TextView myTextView;
...
String data = myTextView.getText().toString();
```

### Parse e evaluate com [expr](https://github.com/darius/expr)

Você pode utilizar o pacote expr (https://github.com/darius/expr), este pacote interpreta e calcula as expressões matemáticas sobre números de ponto flutuante, como `2 + 2` ou `cos(x/(2*pi)) * cos(y/(2*pi))`

1. Instalando:

   Para instalar importe o pacote `expr.jar` para o seu projeto (você irá precisar compilar os `.java` primeiro se você baixar do GitHub. Se você não tiver o `make`, então rode o seguinte comando na pasta que você extraiu o download do GitHub `run javac -O expr/*.java` e depois `jar cf expr.jar expr/*.class`.)
2. Adicionando ao `Activity`:

   Para usar o pacote você pode incluir ele no `MainActivity.java` (ou a outro `Activity`) usando assim `import exp;` (ou algo semelhante)
3. Usando:

   Para usar com o `TextView`, seria algo como:

   ```
   String data = myTextView.getText().toString();

   try {
       expr = Parser.parse(data);
       myTextView.setText(expr.value());
   } catch (SyntaxException e) {
       myTextView.setText(e.explain());
   }
   ```

### ScriptEngine

Conforme disse o usuário @Walkin (usar engine JavaScript pode ser exagero para uma "simples" tarefa), mas ainda sim você pode usa-lo.

O `ScriptEngine` é um motor ECMAScript/JavaScript para realizar o cálculo/operação, conforme está resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3423360/1518921), você terá que usar o `javax.script.*`, que está disponível a partir do *JDK1.6*.

Exemplo com `TextView`:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
...

ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

String data = myTextView.getText().toString();
System.out.println(engine.eval(data));
```

Para setar a sua própria `TextView` ou para outra `TextView`, use:

```
TextView myTextView;
...
String data = myTextView.getText().toString();
myTextView.setText(engine.eval(data));
```

Comment: Concordando com o primeiro comentário da referência, acho que usar uma Engine JavaScript para resolver esse problema, é a mesma coisa que um canhão para matar uma formiga, onde um simples parser de expressões resolve hehe. Outro problema é que qualquer expressão JS é valida, mesmo não sendo matematicamente valida. Talvez valha mais apenas fazer um parser pelo aprendizado também.

Answer (score 12):

Você precisa construir um *avaliador* de expressões matemáticas. Eu fiz um em C, mas, foi para notação polonesa reversa (que não sei se serve para você).

O `TextBox` vai ter retornar uma *string* que é a expressão que precisa ser avaliada, então, você basicamente lê a linha de texto e a medida que vai encontrando um operador ou número, vai guardando em uma pilha/árvore para poder executar as operações na ordem adequada, por exemplo: `1 + (2 * 5)`.

- Você lê o primeiro item: `1` é um número, então põe na pilha.
- Você lê o segundo item: `+` é um operador que vai ser executado com o `1`, põe na pilha de operadores.
- Você lê o terceiro item: `(` - parênteses - então vem aí uma nova
  expressão que devo avaliar antes de devolver o resultado para operar
  com o anterior - abre um ramo na árvore de decisão.
- você lê o quarto item: `2` é um número então põe na nova pilha.
- você lê o quinto item: `*` é um operador - põe na pilha de operadores, vai ser executado com o `2`.
- você lê o último item: `)` - parênteses, é o último e fecha uma ramificação da árvore, então vai puxando da pilha e resolvendo as expressões.

Não sei se deu bem pra entender, mas, é basicamente um exercício de estrutura de dados (pilhas e árvores) onde você, vai encontrando expressões que vão operar 2 em sequência.

A precedência de operadores, é a matemática que diz e as árvores são bifurcações das expressões aninhadas. Se faltar um operador ou parênteses, a árvore/pilha ficará incompleta e a expressão falha automaticamente.

Se não me engano, você pode representar isso como um [Autômato Finito Determinístico](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aut%C3%B4matos_finitos_determin%C3%ADsticos), não me lembro ao certo.

Um código que achei na net:

http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/script/Avaliacao-de-expressoes-matematicas

Comment: Na parte em que diz "puxando da pilha e resolvendo as expressões". Como seria para saber em que ordem deve ser puxado um item dessas pilhas? Por exemplo, puxou o "1" (pilha de números). Em seguida qual ação deve ser realizada? Obter o próximo item na pilha de números ou na de operadores? Como fazer essa verificação?

Comment: A pilha e a arvore são a propria ordem. Pense bem, numa pilha o primeiro que entra é o ultimo que sai, então você resolveria a expressão do ultimo para o primeiro, quando a pilha está vazia, ela foi resolvida. Assim, a cada "desempilhar" você está cada vez mais proximo do fim da expressão, outra dica, é que os operadores geralmente sao binários, precisam sempre de 2 elementos para executar, então você não precisa necessariamente de uma pilha ou mais de uma, pode usar uma arvore binária tambem, a ordem ainda é do final da arvore para o primeiro no.

Comment: Sei que a resposta é bem antiga, mas mesmo assim, tenho que comentar que um autômato finito determinístico não serve para isso, tem que ser um [autômato de pilha](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aut%C3%B4mato_com_pilha). A razão disso é que um autômato finito não é capaz de lembrar quais são os parênteses abertos ou onde eles abriram.

Answer (score 5):

Resposta pragmática (não reinvente a roda). Use uma das muitas bibliotecas para avaliar expressões em Java.

## Links:

- [Jep](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/) (proprietária)
- [expr](https://github.com/darius/expr)
- [JEval](http://jeval.sourceforge.net/)
- [MathEval](http://softwaremonkey.org/Code/MathEval)
- [exp4j](http://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/)
- [EvalEx](https://github.com/uklimaschewski/EvalEx)
- [expression-evaluator-demo](https://github.com/Shy-Ta/expression-evaluator-demo)

Existem tantas que é mais fácil buscar diretamente no Google. Seu desafio é selecionar a melhor biblioteca para o seu caso particular.

---

## Fontes

- [SOen: Evaluating a math expression given in string form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3422673/664577)
- [SOen: What's a good library for parsing mathematical expressions in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2226863/664577)