# Como fazer para o programa reconhecer ' x ' como multiplicação?

Tags: java

Tem como tratar x como *, pois o usuário vai digitar x para multiplicar num número, teria como o programa reconhecer x como multiplicação via a código?

exemplo `double b = 5 x 5;`

Comment: Quando você diz "usuário" quer dizer a pessoa que usa o sistema que você criou em Java ou você mesmo programando em Java? Não ficou claro se vc pretende trocar o `*` por `x` na hora de programar (isto é, no código) ou fazer a avaliação da expressão matemática digitada pelo usuário em uma UI. Se for o segundo caso, dé uma olhada nesta outra pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51324/como-calcular-express%C3%A3o-matematicas-numa-string

Comment: No código Java em si, não. Mas na entrada de dados dele, claro que tem, depende de como você está cuidando disto. Edite a pergunta postando seu código.

Comment: mesmo o usuário mais leigo utiliza o *, não faz sentido pensar que ele irá digitar X...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não. O operador de multiplicação no Java é o `*`. Porém, você pode fazer isso para o usuário final.

Por exemplo, ele até pode digitar `5 x 5` como uma multiplicação, daí o programa recebe a string e substitui o `x` por `*` e avaliar matematicamente a expressão resultante da substituição.

#### Por que é assim?

Vamos supor as seguintes instruções matemáticas num código Java:

```
int x = 10;
int a = 10 * x; //Compila corretamente, com a recebendo o valor 100;
int b = 10 x x; //Como deve ser entendido cada x? Um é multiplicação e outro é identificador?
                //Duas multiplicações? 
                //Dois identificadores?
```

A linguagem deve ser uniforme e precisa. Caso contrário, imprevisibilidades ocorrem e ninguém sabe por que diabos o código não faz o que deveria ser feito.

#### Como solucionar esse problema?

Quando você recebe a entrada do usuário, você pode alterá-la sem o conhecimento dele e mostrar o resultado correto com uma expressão diferente da dele, desde que a expressão usada para calcular seja equivalente à que o usuário deu ao programa.

**Exemplo:** Calculadora com interface gráfica

Vamos supor uma calculadora tradicional, com números de 0 a 9 e apenas o operador de multiplicação (para simplificar).

Cada número coloca o valor dele no visor e o botão de multiplicação coloca a letra `x`. O que o botão de `=` deveria fazer?

O algoritmo seria:

1. Recuperar a string que o usuário criou e atribuir a uma variável;
2. Substituir todos os `x` da variável por `*`. Facilmente feito com `replaceAll`, e note que não é necessário que essa String nova seja mostrada ao usuário;
3. Fazer o parsing dos números que cada `*` circunda e multiplicar;
4. Substituir na string com o resultado;
5. String só tem números? Mostrar ao usuário;
6. Caso contrário, volte ao passo 3.

Answer (score 2):

Pela tag da pergunta, vou presumir que você está implementando em Java.

Existem várias maneiras de fazer isso, a que vou sugerir é apenas uma delas, não necessariamente a melhor ou mais simples:

1. Fazer o parsing da expressão e converter os símbolos que o usuário entende para o símbolos que a linguagem entende. Ex.: de "b = 5 x 5" para "b = 5 * 5".
2. Passar a string processada para uma biblioteca que faça isso para você, como por exemplo, o [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/)

Um exemplo hipotético usando BeanShell seria:

```
Interpreter interp = new Interpreter();
interp.eval("b = 5 * 5");
System.out.println("resultado: b="+interpreter.get("b"));
```