# Conversão de um cálculo (String) para double

Tags: java

Eu tenho uma `String conta` que sempre é um cálculo (4+4, por exemplo), e quero passar esse valor para o `resultado` que no caso é um `double`, já tentei usar o método `parse`, porém não obtive sucesso.

Existe algum outro jeito de fazer essa conversão ?

***Código:***

```
resultado = Double.parseDouble(conta);
System.out.println(resultado);
```

***Erro:***

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4+4"

Lembrando que o erro está indicando justamente a linha que eu faço a conversão.

Comment: "4+4" é uma string, não uma operação matematica e nem um numeral para o java. Logo, você não vai conseguir converter. Se quer somar e converter o resultado em double, precisa separar os valores numéricos isoladamente, fazer a soma e depois converter.

Comment: Mas na hora que eu converto "4+4" para double não seria a mesma coisa de escrever ´resultado = 4+4´ ?

Comment: Não, como eu disse, isso pro java é uma string, ele não sabe que se trata de uma operação aritmetica.

Comment: Pergunta relacionada [Como calcular expressão matematicas numa string?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51324/como-calcular-express%c3%a3o-matematicas-numa-string)